# Creating a globe from a world map svg using the svg ID

Tags: json, svg

I am working on an svg world map using highcharts and therefore I load the world map data using JSON as below:

```
$.getJSON('data.json', function (data) {...
```

JSON file that contains the below snippet but for all countries of the world.

```
[
{
    "code": "AF",
    "value": 53,
    "name": "Afghanistan"
},
{
    "code": "AL",
    "value": 117,
    "name": "Albania"
},
{
    "code": "DZ",
    "value": 15,
    "name": "Algeria"
},
{
    "code": "AS",
    "value": 342,
    "name": "American Samoa"
},
```

Highcharts generates the svg paths from this json data and each country path has a unique ID. How can I turn this highcharts generated map into a globe?

Thanks

Comment: In the highcharts we have "flat" maps so globe is not available, as I understand you well.

Comment: That is why I am looking into converting the flat map generated by highcharts into a globe using other frameworks such as webGl or D3 that allow me to pass ID of the highcharts generated svg and not from JSON asthis will create both flat map and globe